# If/Else Statements Socket.io Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have been trying to add an If/Else statement to my Socket.io client for a personal project I've been working on. The end goal is to create a Bitcoin ticker with 2 values (oldPrice and newPrice) sent from the server. I would like to be able to change the styling and bg color depending on the values.

This is what I have to far:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1000');

socket.on('newPrice', function(data){
   var newPrice = data.value  
});

socket.on('oldPrice', function(data){
   var oldPrice = data.value    
});
```

I would like to add this:

```
if (newPrice < oldPrice) {

            }else if (newPrice > oldPrice) {

            }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem. If I understood your problem correctly, the easiest solution might me something like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1000');

var oldPrice,newPrice;

socket.on('newPrice', function(data){
   newPrice = data.value;
   update();  
});

socket.on('oldPrice', function(data){
   oldPrice = data.value;
   update();    
});

function update() {

    if (newPrice < oldPrice) {
      //do your stuff
    }
    else {
      //do something else
    }    

}
```

I hope this will help.